# Rotate columns and rows in matrix

Tags: matlab

how can I rotate columns and rows in a matrix n times. For example:
If I have matrix

```
A= [1,2,3;
    4,5,6;
    7,8,9]
```

and want to rotate all rows n = 1, it should give me

```
R= [7,8,9;
    1,2,3;
    4,5,6].
```

The program should work for every n x n matrix and it should also be possible to rotate columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) to shift all of the rows down one

```
R = circshift(A, [1 0]);
```

The second input specifies the shift to apply in the first (rows) and second (columns) dimensions. In your initial case since you don't want to shift columns, we leave that as zero.

If instead we want to shift the rows by 1 and the columns by 2 we could do:

```
R = circshift(A, [2 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how I can create a function which does exactly the same as circshift, but without using circshift?

Comment: @zer0kai You could play around with using `mod` to shift the indices of the rows ad columns